# How do I get a SOAPUI LoadTest to log all groovy script output?

Tags: groovy, soapui, load-testing

Is there any way to get SOAP UI to log test case output during load tests?

I have a groovy script that produces log output but only when the test case is run by itself. 
I need to see the same output when it's run as part of a Load Test...

Thanks
Chris

Comment: If I remember right, log will be disabled while running the load tests. By the way, you have not mentioned any specific details, just mentioned test case output, can you please precise it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/scripting-possibilities.html#1-Setup-and-TearDown-scripts):

> ...please note that the script log is by default disabled during execution of a LoadTest, you can enable it in the Global Preferences [UI Settings tab](https://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/reference/preferences-and-settings.html#UI-Settings).

Comment: I have seen this guidance before but when you "don't disable" the log basically shows the message requests, responses and if they pass tests - not the actual logging produced from the Groovy script.  Any thoughts on how to get the actual Groovy script logging?

Comment: @DrDave If you use the normal `log.info ...`, then that should be (dis|en)abled with this switch.

Comment: I do use the log.info.  It is only during load testing that this occurs - with a normal (functional) test it logs as expected